# Reorganizing DataFrame and writing to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
by_timeofday=  

                                  Area1      Area2      Area3          Area4
Time                                                                          
Day (9AM-6PM)                       1     0.411111     0.405556           0   
Evening (6PM-10PM)                  1     0.650000     0.650000           0   
Morning (5AM-9AM)                   1     1.000000     1.000000           0   
Night (10PM-5AM)                    1     1.000000     1.000000           0
```

This DataFrame is also associated with a specific *Date* and a *District* value.

I want to output the content of this DataFrame into a SQL database, that will look the following way/contain the following info:

**TABLE NAME**: *District_Area#*

**TABLE CONTENT** (example shown for Area2):

```
Date         Morning (5AM-9AM)      Day (9AM-6PM)     Evening (6PM-10PM)     Night (10PM-5AM)
01.01.2011       1.000000             0.411111             0.650000             1.000000
```

The SQL table should get more rows as different DataFrames get written to SQL. Can anyone help me create some code that will reorganize my data and write it to SQL this way? I'm very new to Python and unfortunately have not found a lot of directly helpful information looking at the Pandas and SQL documentation.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Pandas DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

You can take your (partial) DataFrame and write it to a SQL database. This is a basic example (using sqlite):

```
 import sqlite3 as sql
 con = sql.connect(PATH_TO_DATABASE)
 table_name = test
 by_timeofday.to_sql(name=table_name, con=con, FURTHER_OPTIONS) # write full df to sql
```

> The SQL table should get more rows as different DataFrames get written
>   to SQL.

In this case you could set the option in df.to_sql():

> if_exists: append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.

**Edit:**

To reorganise a new DataFrame (step by step):

```
In[30]: by_timeofday
Out[30]: 
          Area1     Area2     Area3  Area4
Day          1  0.411111  0.405556      0
Evening      1  0.650000  0.650000      0
Morning      1  1.000000  1.000000      0
Night        1  1.000000  1.000000      0

In[33]: by_timeofday.loc[:,"Area2"]  # this is a 'Series' not a 'DataFrame'
Out[33]: 
Day        0.411111
Evening    0.650000
Morning    1.000000
Night      1.000000

In[36]: df = pd.DataFrame(by_timeofday.loc[:,"Area2"])  # make 'DataFrame' out of the 'Series'
Out[36]: 
            Area2
Day      0.411111
Evening  0.650000
Morning  1.000000
Night    1.000000

In[41]: df.T # transpose
Out[41]: 
            Day  Evening  Morning  Night
Area2  0.411111     0.65        1      1

In[44]: df = pd.DataFrame(by_timeofday.loc[:,"Area2"]).T  # all in one
Out[44]: 
            Day  Evening  Morning  Night
Area2  0.411111     0.65        1      1

# add date:
In[45]: df["Date"] = "01.01.2011"
In[46]: df
Out[46]: 
            Day  Evening  Morning  Night        Date
Area2  0.411111     0.65        1      1  01.01.2011
```

Comment: I did look at this, but will this allow me to reorganize the data the way I mentioned above within the database later? I thought I wouldn't be able to and would have to write it to the database in the form I wanted it to be displayed.

Comment: I edit it to reorganise the DataFrame - basically the 'all in one' is (I hope) what you need. But with the other single steps you can better understand it.

Comment: I'm currently working something similar into my code. Thank you, the edit was very helpful.